# retryAnalyzer with dependsOnGroups

Tags: java, testing, testng

I have Selenium tests that every once in a while fail, so I want a retryAnalyzer to force the tests to rerun. Now I'm adding some tests dependencies with dependsOnGroups. But if a selenium test fails and passes the second time, the test depending on it will be skipped.

What I want is testRetryAndPass passes once (regardless of it being a retry or not), then I want testDependOnGroup to run. Right now testDependOnGroup is skipped.

The test code:

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups = "test")
public void testDependOnGroup()
{
    assertTrue( true );
}

@Test( groups = { "test" }, retryAnalyzer = RetryAnalyzer.class )
public void testRetryAndPass()
{
    if ( RetryAnalyzer.retryCount == 0 )
    {
        assertTrue( false );
    }
    else
    {
        assertTrue( true );
    }
}
```

RetryAnalyzer:

```
public class RetryAnalyzer extends TestListenerAdapter implements IRetryAnalyzer
{
   private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( RetryAnalyzer.class );

   public static int retryCount = 0;
   public static final int MAX_RETRIES = 1;

   @Override
   public boolean retry( ITestResult result )
   {
       logger.info( "Running retry for " + result.getMethod() );
       boolean retryFunction = false;
       if ( retryCount < MAX_RETRIES )
       {
           retryCount++;
           retryFunction = true;
       }

       return retryFunction;
   }
}
```

I will gladly answer any questions you may have.